# Convert already inserted \n to <br/> draft-js with React

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

**Why**

I'm using `draft-js` to support rich text in editor fields of an app. This addition is new, and before I had raw text and now that text is exported as HTML.

**What**

Some content had line spaces `\n` and now that content will show as a single paragraph.

**How**

I know that `draft-js` only converts the raw text to html when changed. Even though `draft-js` should convert the `\n` is not converted.